Azure Load ballencer public IP with cloudflate certificate
We have an Azure Load balancer with a front-end static public IP. We have set a custom DNS label as well. Is it possible to add an SSL certificate to this setup? if so what is the process?


Azure Load Balancer is a Network Layer 4 balancer, for balancing TCP and UDP traffic and doesn't support SSL offloading.If you want to use SSL certificate, you can use Application Gateway.

If the backend services serve an SSL certificate from Kestrel after downloading from Keyvalut. Is that a good design?

Load balancer operates on layer 4 and doesn't provide application layer gateway functionality. Protocol handshakes always occur directly between the client and the backend pool instance. Because the load balancer doesn't interact with the TCP payload nor does it provide TLS offload, you can build comprehensive encrypted scenarios. Using load balancer gains large scale-out for TLS applications by ending the TLS connection on the VM itself. For example, your TLS session keying capacity is only limited by the type and number of VMs you add to the backend pool.

Thanks, we already have the Load balancer coming from the Azure service fabric. What is the best option for us? Do we need to put the  Application Gateway in front of the LB? or can application Gateway access the service fabric reverse proxy?

Application Gateway works at the application layer (Layer 7 in the OSI network reference stack). It acts as a reverse-proxy service, terminating the client connection and forwarding requests to back-end endpoints, refer this link &  What Application Gateway has to offer

Azure Load Balancer is a Network Layer 4 balancer, for balancing TCP and UDP traffic and doesn't support SSL offloading.If you want to use SSL certificate, you can use Application Gateway.
The Azure Load Balancer is Layer 4 (TCP/UDP) load balancer, for balancing network layer 4 and primarily handles TCP and UDP traffic. Azure Load Balancer itself does not support SSL offloading.
If you require SSL termination and want to use SSL certificates use Azure Application Gateway instead of Azure Load Balancer.
Azure Application Gateway is a Layer 7 (HTTP/HTTPS) load balancer that provides application-level load balancing, It allows you to offload SSL for enhancing security and performance.
Application Gateway works at the application layer 7 . It acts as a reverse-proxy service, terminating the client connection and forwarding requests to back-end endpoints. for more details refer the Stack Link by Peter Bons
Reference: Does Azure Load Balancer support TLS/SSL termination?
Loadbalancer for backend Services secured with SSL
When to use Azure Application Gateway
